# react-admin: Material Design Update

Tags: react-admin

How much effort would it be to update the framework to the newest material design standards eg used in material-ui?
Specifically I'm looking into updating text-input fields to the outline textfield design. Is there a way to easily "import" the newest material design standards on bulk without touching every single component?

Answer (score 1):

I think it's a great deal of work indeed: You'll need to fork the ra-ui-materialui package, upgrade the dependency to material_ui, and fix all the things. And you can trow away your work just after that, since material-ui is again going to break BC with V4.

This has been discussed in the react-admin repository:

> Material-ui 3 is a BC break over material-ui 1, so upgrading that dependency would be a BC break for react-admin, too. We'd have to release react-admin 3.0. Since the latest stable (2.0) is not that old (May 2018), we'll wait a few more weeks before breaking BC again.

I advise you to use material ui v1, or to wait a few more months until the react-admin core team makes the switch to material ui v4.